# Remote download files for Android (Air mobile)

Tags: android, actionscript-3, air

To make the app smaller, I want to download specific big files by the user.

Want to check whether the file in the directory, if not, download it (show the progress for the user) and copy it to the specified directory. 
How do I implement it correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `File` class should work.

```
var fileToCheck:File=File.applicationStorageDirectory.resolvePath("some-file.txt");
if(!fileToCheck.exists) {
    //download file
}
```

Downloading a file from AIR is another question, which has already been answered here:
[Download a file with Adobe AIR](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/342994/download-a-file-with-adobe-air)

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at Android's [`DownloadManager`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DownloadManager.html) class.

Comment: Air mobile. I do not know why miss tags: Air, actionscript 3

Comment: Are you trying to download from within an Adobe Air app, or from a Java-based Android app?